# flask Function to create route

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

i'm building an app similar to `myPhpAdmain`

i need to allow users in session to create route (aka: `@app.route`)  for the page they require

```
@app.route('/<x>')
def <x>():

  return render_template (<x>+'.html')
```

where `x` is a variable that has been given by a user through the front-end

`x = request.form.get('x')`

how can I allow users to create Pages route like that by a function without allowing them to write it themselves in my flask app ?

Comment: is `x` passed via a form or as a part of the URL?

Comment: @Rishav yes via a form or via ajax maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [variable routing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules):

> ```
> @app.route('/<x>')
> def user_route(x):
>     return render_template(f"{x}.html")
> ```